# How can I tell Python that there is page that is different for the other with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a Python script based on **BeautifulSoup** and **Selenium** that scapes data from Google Maps. The page is supposed to deliver a list of results. However, when there is a single result, the page is different. How can I inform Python this happens to pass additional instructions?

My current script is:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import csv
from csv import writer
import random
import os

count = 0
print(os.getcwd())
with open('exported_data.csv', 'a+', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f_header:
    csv_header = writer(f_header)
    csv_header.writerow(['Company Name', 'Rating'])

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    with open('terms_to_search.csv') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for row in csv_reader:
            try:
                page = browser.new_page()
                term_searched = row[0]
                name = []
                rating = []
                page.goto('https://www.google.com/maps/')
                page.fill('xpath=//*[@id="searchboxinput"]', f'{row[0]}')
                time.sleep(3)
                page.click('xpath=//*[@id="searchbox-searchbutton"]', timeout=0)
                time.sleep(3)
                page.mouse.move(0,100)
                while not page.is_visible('span.HlvSq'):
                    count = count + 1
                    if count < 50:
                        page.mouse.wheel(0,500)
                        time.sleep(random.randint(1,2))
                        page.mouse.wheel(0,500)
                        time.sleep(random.randint(1,2))
                        page.mouse.wheel(0,500)
                        time.sleep(random.randint(1,2))
                        page.mouse.wheel(0,500)
                        time.sleep(random.randint(1,2))
                        page.mouse.wheel(0,500)
                        time.sleep(random.randint(1,2))
                        page.mouse.wheel(0,500)
                        time.sleep(random.randint(1,2))
                    else:
                        page.click('xpath=//*[@id="searchbox-searchbutton"]', timeout=60)
                        count = 0
                        time.sleep(5)
                        page.mouse.move(0,100)
                count = 0
                time.sleep(10)
                html = page.inner_html('html')
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
                try:
                    results = soup.find('div', class_='m6QErb DxyBCb kA9KIf dS8AEf ecceSd').find_all('div', class_='lI9IFe')
                except:
                    pass
              
                for result in results:   
                    try:
                        name = result.find('div', class_='qBF1Pd fontHeadlineSmall').text.strip()
                    except:
                        pass
                    try:
                        rating = result.find('span', class_='MW4etd').text.strip()
                    except:
                        pass

                    data = [name, rating, term_searched]

                    with open('exported_data.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f:
                        csv_writer = writer(f)
                        csv_writer.writerow(data)
                        f.close()
                    website = ''
                count+=1    
                page.close()
                
            except:
                pass
```

Searches (within a csv):

```
"Porto Alegre, RS Teather"
"Itaqui, RS Teather"
```

(the problem happens in the second search)

My idea is to have something like:

```py
if page results different from the previous one:
      #do this
```

Would appreciate any help.
Thank you!

Comment: Just use an if-statement to search for the **unique characteristic** of that page. If present, then do one thing, if not present, do the other.

Comment: i would suggest u to use a for loop instead of manually typing those mouse scrolling code

Comment: can u give me some examples of the places that u r searching in google maps?

Comment: @GhostOps sure. Will update the question.

Comment: i don't see the span.HlvSq element in the webpage, its stuck in an infinite loop for me

Comment: @GhostOps exactly this, I think. How could I solve??

Comment: @Vinícius well, tell me clearly what u r trying to achieve, so that i can help u. ur question is not clear to me.

Comment: @GhostOps the first search term returns a list of results from Google maps. The second one return a place rahter than this list (this happens when there is a single result). My goal is to skip the second case

Comment: so, all u want to do is to scroll through those search results automatically instead of manually scrolling them, and ignore if its a single search result as it shows the description of a place, right?

Comment: Exactly @GhostOps

Comment: may i ask u why u r using try except while u r just doing nothing on the except block? u could've just remove the try code block

Comment: as u have mentioned above, is that the actual form of data in the csv file? do they exist in quotes? cuz im getting the results with the quotes in the exported_data.csv file

Comment: @GhostOps, quotes are right. Agree with you regarding try/except. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are looking for list of search results, you would get zero such search result elements in a single result page

So using that logic, all you have to do is to check whether the div element that holds the list of search elements exists or not

It can be done like this in your code

```py
html = page.inner_html('html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'm6QErb DxyBCb kA9KIf dS8AEf ecceSd', 'aria-label': True})
if results is None:
    # This denotes that there's no list of search results, you can exit the code right here
    ...

results = results.find_all('div', class_='lI9IFe')
```

**EDIT:** The above code would only work while you are parsing the code in BeautifulSoup, it will not work in the playwright driver (my bad)

So the logic stays the same, search for the parent div, whose children are the search results arranged in a list. If it doesn't exist, then stop the code (maybe you can just skip the current iteration and move on to the next search)

And for that, all I've done is add one more check in the while loop

```py
while page.query_selector('div.m6QErb.DxyBCb.kA9KIf.dS8AEf.ecceSd[aria-label]') and not page.is_visible('span.HlvSq'):
```

Therefore, Final code (Refractored some parts of it by myself)

```py
import csv
import os
import sys
import time
from csv import writer
from random import randint

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

count = 0
print(os.getcwd())
with open('exported_data.csv', 'a+', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f_header:
    csv_header = writer(f_header)
    csv_header.writerow(['Company Name', 'Rating'])

with sync_playwright() as p:
    try:
        browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        with open('terms_to_search.csv') as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
            for term_searched, *_ in csv_reader:
                page = browser.new_page()
                page.goto('https://www.google.com/maps/')
                page.fill('xpath=//*[@id="searchboxinput"]', term_searched)
                time.sleep(3)
                page.click('xpath=//*[@id="searchbox-searchbutton"]', timeout=0)
                time.sleep(3)
                page.mouse.move(0,100)
                count = 0
                while page.query_selector('div.m6QErb.DxyBCb.kA9KIf.dS8AEf.ecceSd[aria-label]') and not page.is_visible('span.HlvSq'):
                    count += 1
                    if count < 50:
                        for _ in range(6):
                            page.mouse.wheel(0,500)
                            time.sleep(randint(1,2))
                    else:
                        page.click('xpath=//*[@id="searchbox-searchbutton"]', timeout=60)
                        time.sleep(5)
                        page.mouse.move(0,100)

                time.sleep(10)
                html = page.inner_html('body')
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
                results = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'm6QErb DxyBCb kA9KIf dS8AEf ecceSd', 'aria-label': True})
                if results is None:
                    continue
                    # ------ or ---------
                    # page.close()
                    # sys.exit()

                results = results.find_all('div', class_='lI9IFe')
                for result in results:
                    name = result.find('div', class_='qBF1Pd fontHeadlineSmall').get_text(strip=True)
                    rating = result.find('span', class_='MW4etd').get_text(strip=True)
                    data = [name, rating, term_searched]

                    with open('exported_data.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f:
                        csv_writer = writer(f)
                        csv_writer.writerow(data)

                count += 1
    finally:
        page.close()
        browser.close()
```

Tell me if it's not working...

Comment: Understood. Will test soon and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: In fact, same output. Selenium continues to working as in the other pages. I tried "pass" and also "page.close()".

Comment: @Vinícius try the code without try except pass part, and tell me whats the output

Comment: Yes, I excluded them before testing

Comment: @Vinícius now, i've edited my answer, check it now and tell me if its not working...

Comment: now it works! Really thank you for your help!! Do you suggest some sources to study about scraping? Best wishes!

Comment: @Vinícius nah man, its just a small problem, even you could've solved it if u just take a break, and code afterwards. And if you find this answer helpful, please consider upvoting the answer

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure how to upvote here, but I will try to figure out. Best!